# In stored procedure if null value found it should skip that insert query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables one is

```
peson contains(personid Identity, firstname,Lastname,PlaceOfBirth,Gender)
```

and another

```
Education contains (Eduid identity, egreename,boardUniver,yearOfPassing,obtainedMarks, personid)
```

now my problem is that each person have more than 1 degree, but some have 1 or 2 degree, so how can i skip the insert queries?

First Table

```
Create table person(personid int Identity(1,1) primary key, firstname nvarchar(40), Lastname nvarchar(40), PlaceOfBirth nvarchar(40), Gender nvarchar(10))
```

Second Table

```
create table Education(Eduid int identity(1,1) primary key, Degreename nvarchar(40), boardUniver nvarchar(40), yearOfPassing nvarchar(40), obtainedMarks numeric(10,2), personid int, 
constraint fk_eduPerson foreign key (personid) references person(personid))
```

Procedure to store information

```
Create procedure EmpDetails
(
    @Firstname nvarchar(40),  @Lastname nvarchar(40), @PlaceOfBirth nvarchar(40), @Gender nvarchar(8), 
    @Degreename0 int, @boardUniver0 nvarchar(40), @yearOfPassing0 nvarchar(20), @obtainedMarks0 int,
    @Degreename1 int, @boardUniver1 nvarchar(40), @yearOfPassing1 nvarchar(20), @obtainedMarks1 int,
    @Degreename2 int, @boardUniver2 nvarchar(40), @yearOfPassing2 nvarchar(20), @obtainedMarks2 int, 
)
AS BEGIN
declare @personid int
INSERT INTO person(firstname,Lastname,PlaceOfBirth,Gender) values(@firstname,@Lastname,@PlaceOfBirth,@Gender)
SELECT @personid=@@IDENTITY
if(@Degreename0 !=NULL)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Education(Degreename,boardUniver,yearOfPassing,obtainedMarks, personid) values (@Degreename0,@boardUniver0,@yearOfPassing0,@obtainedMarks0, @personid)
    END
IF(@Degreename1 !=null)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Education(Degreename,boardUniver,yearOfPassing,obtainedMarks, personid) values (@Degreename1,@boardUniver1,@yearOfPassing1,@obtainedMarks1, @personid)
  END
IF(@Degreename2!=null)
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Education(Degreename,boardUniver,yearOfPassing,obtainedMarks, personid) values (@Degreename2,@boardUniver2,@yearOfPassing2,@obtainedMarks2,@personid)
    END
END
```

This is not working.. this inserts all rows empty.. is there any other solution to do this?
Please give suggestion if any other.. Thanks

Comment: It would be better to pass this degree data as [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) or, if they're not available in your version, XML data. That way you can perform a multi-row insert of exactly as many rows as are passed to you (and you don't need to edit your procedure if someone turns up with a 4th degree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`. In most relational databases, the comparison operators return false if either input is `NULL`, even if they both are. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75798/12/0) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating the behavior.

(Sorry. That SQL Fiddle really works.)

Admittedly, this is confusing, as that fact should mean all your `INSERT`s are skipped. I don't see anything here that would insert empty rows.

Comment: If one of the answers posted solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer. If neither of these fixed your issue, consider posting your own answer. After a certain amount of time, StackOverflow will let you accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
Create procedure EmpDetails
(
    ...
)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @personid INT
    INSERT INTO Person (firstname, Lastname, PlaceOfBirth, Gender)
    SELECT @firstname, @Lastname, @PlaceOfBirth, @Gender

    SELECT @personid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Education (Degreename, boardUniver, yearOfPassing, obtainedMarks, PersonID)

    SELECT a = @Degreename0, b = @boardUniver0, c = @yearOfPassing0, d = @obtainedMarks0, e = @personid
    WHERE @Degreename0 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT @Degreename1, @boardUniver1, @yearOfPassing1, @obtainedMarks1, @personid
    WHERE @Degreename1 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT @Degreename2, @boardUniver2, @yearOfPassing2, @obtainedMarks2, @personid
    WHERE @Degreename2 IS NOT NULL

END
```